# Find Facebook profile by email address in 2022

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are many similar questions on SO already, but things have changed a **lot** since the Cambridge Analytica scandal and the tightening of users' privacy, so I want to clarify the context: how can I find a Facebook profile (i.e. a Facebook user object) using an email address in the year 2022?

I understand that the results may be limited to only users who have opted to make their profiles public, but I am not seeing anything relevant in the Facebook API documentation, e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ has nothing about performing a SEARCH.  Is this type of action no longer possible?  It's been a few years since I had to use it, but the Facebook API is now completely unrecognizable to me.  Surely scraping the HTML from a search-result page is not the way to accomplish this task?

Comment: No there is no way. You can't get any info about users that haven't granted permission to your app.